# Importing generic implicits from class instances

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit

I'm trying to make a generic implicit provider which can create an implicit value for a given type, something in the lines of:

```
trait Evidence[T]

class ImplicitProvider[T] {
  class Implementation extends Evidence[T]
  implicit val evidence: Evidence[T] = new Implementation
}
```

To use this implicit, I create a `val provider = new ImplicitProvider[T]` instance where necessary and import from it `import provider._`. This works fine as long as there is just one instance. However sometimes implicits for several types are needed in one place

```
case class A()
case class B()

class Test extends App {
  val aProvider = new ImplicitProvider[A]
  val bProvider = new ImplicitProvider[B]

  import aProvider._
  import bProvider._

  val a = implicitly[Evidence[A]]
  val b = implicitly[Evidence[B]]
}
```

And this fails to compile with `could not find implicit value for parameter` and `not enough arguments for method implicitly` errors.

If I use implicit vals from providers directly, everything starts to work again.

```
implicit val aEvidence = aProvider.evidence
implicit val bEvidence = bProvider.evidence
```

However I'm trying to avoid importing individual values, as there are actually several implicits inside each provider and the goal is to abstract them if possible.

Can this be achieved somehow or do I want too much from the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you import from both objects, you're bringing in two entities that have colliding names: `evidence` in `aProvider` and `evidence` in `bProvider`. The compiler cannot disambiguate those, both because of how its implemented, and because it'd be a bad idea for implicits, which can already be arcane, to be able to do things that cannot be done explicitly (disambiguating between clashing names).

What I don't understand is what the point of `ImplicitProvider` is. You can pull the `Implementation` class out to the top level and have an `object` somewhere that holds the `implicit val`s.

```
class Implementation[T] extends Evidence[T]

object Evidence {
  implicit val aEvidence: Evidence[A] = new Implementation[A]
  implicit val bEvidence: Evidence[B] = new Implementation[B]
}

// Usage:
import Evidence._
implicitly[Evidence[A]]
implicitly[Evidence[B]]
```

Now, there is no name clash.

If you need to have an actual `ImplicitProvider`, you can instead do this:

```
class ImplicitProvider[T] { ... }

object ImplicitProviders {
  implicit val aProvider = new ImplicitProvider[A]
  implicit val bProvider = new ImplicitProvider[B]

  implicit def ImplicitProvider2Evidence[T: ImplicitProvider]: Evidence[T]
    = implicitly[ImplicitProvider[T]].evidence
}

// Usage
import ImplicitProviders._
// ...
```

Comment: For some reason I always thought implicits resolution worked only by type, not taking names into account.

Actual purpose of `ImplicitProvider` in my case is to provide Circe `Encoder`/`Decoder` instances for certain types of objects. These types are not known beforehand, so you can't have ready-made instances in an object. I was trying to achieve minimum boilerplate for the user, without the need to import or reference individual `Encoder`s/`Decoder`s.

Thanks for the implicit conversion tip, it was the missing link. It did just what was needed.